# Overwrite create method of res.users to add users upon creation to a group

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, odoo

I created a simple function which add users to a custom group. its working fine through button but the problem is i have to click the button every time the new user is create otherwise he will not be able to access the custom module so i want to overwrite create method of res.users and include add_to_group function. in result if someone signup through website they will be automatically added to the group.

here is my code

```
@api.multi
def add_to_group(self):
    group = self.env['res.groups'].search([('name','=','Applicant)]) #search for my custom group
    user_id = self.id #get the current user id
    group.users = [user_id] #add the user to the group
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override create method in res.users model doing like:

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    res = super(ResUsers, self).create(vals)
    res.add_to_group()
    return res
```